# store data in a array throw loop using javascript

Tags: javascript

i want to Create a script to generate an html  with the following specifications.

1. Class name field is mandatory.
2. Based on the value of class variable field generate the number of data type and variable name fields.
3. Based on the value of functions field generate the number of return type, function name and
   parameters fields.
4. Based on the value of parameter field generate the number of data type and variable name fields.
5. Function name and Variable name must start with alphabets.
6. When the user clicks the Generate code show the output.
7. Data Type /Return Type combo box values should be int, float, double and void.
8. Return Type combo box values should be int, float, double and void.

this is my code

```js
        function change() {
            var txt = ""
            var txt2 = ""
            var m = document.getElementById("m")
            var f = document.getElementById("f")
            var t1 = document.getElementById("Text2").value
           
            var array = new Array()
            txt2 += "Class " + t3 + "<br /> {"
            
            
            if (t1 == 0) {
                txt += ""
            }
            else {
                
                for (var a = 0; a < t1; a++){

                    for (var i = 0; i < t1-1; i++) {
                        txt += "Data type <select id='" + i + "'>"
                        txt += "<option value='INT'> int  </option>"
                        txt += "<option value='FLOOT'> floot  </option>"
                        txt += "<option value='VOID'> void  </option>"
                        txt += "<option value='DOUBLE'> double  </option>"
                        txt += "</select> &nbsp;&nbsp;"
                        
                        
                        for (var n = 0; n < i; n++) {
                            document.write(array[n] + "<br>");
                            
                        }
                        

                        
                    }

                    txt += "Variable name <input type='text' id='" + a + "' /> <br />"
                    m.innerHTML = txt
                    txt2 += "&nbsp;" + document.getElementById(a).value 
                    txt2 += "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + document.getElementById(i)
                }
               
                
            }
           
            f.innerHTML = txt2

            
        }

    </script>
```

```html
 

Enter Class Name <input id="Text1" type="text" /> <br /><br />

    Enter Number of Class variables <input id="Text2" type="text" onchange="change()" /> <br /> <br />
    <h5 id="m"> </h5>
    Enter Number of Functions <input id="Text3" type="text" onchange="change()" /> <br />
    <br /><br />

    <h5 id="f"> </h5>

    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="change()" />
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is almost exemplary, with clear requirements and (almost) executable code. However, please also add the problem statement. What doesn't work? What behaviour are you getting that you don't want, and what behaviour is missing? What test input should we enter to reproduce your problem? What should happen, and what is happening instead?

Comment: i want to get the values from the loop by storing them in an array. then i want to use this values to show it in the final output.. my problem is with the loop i cant get the values and show it in final output

Comment: where you fill your `array`?

Comment: i fill my array from loop based on the user input. first the loop will generate [input] and from that input i want to store it in array so i can use it later on

Answer (score 0):

If you check the console, you will find the error: "t3 is not defined". This comes because you never defined `t3`. If I put in the following near the top of your function, it works (up to a point):

```
var t3 = document.getElementById("Text1").value;
```

It will eventually break, since you have more problems than that. For one thing, a big reason why your `array` isn't printing is because you never defined its contents.

Please note that it is a hell for anyone to read code where the variable `t1` is contents of element `Text2`, and `t3` content of `Text2`, and where a loop counters are `a`, `i` and `n`. Consider changing variable names to `className`, `methodCount`, `variableCount`, etc. It is hell for me right now, and I guarantee it will be hell for you too in about a week, if it isn't already.

Also, be aware that `document.write` is a very dangerous and destructive force. Use it only when it is absolutely necessary, and even then think thrice. Use `element.innerHTML = ...`, or `element.appendChild(...)` with `document.createElement(...)`. The first method is easier, and it is almost always a better idea and more controllable than `document.write`. I see you are already using `innerHTML`, so this should not be hard. Treat `document.write` as if it is radioactive: if you absolutely *have* to touch it, be smart, and wear a biohazard suit.

Finally, your loops do not do what you want, not even close. As I said, it was hard to even follow your logic there due to nonsensical variable names and weird limits. You will find that when you give your variables better names, you will get clarity to see what your program is actually doing.

Post-finally, a silly observation: "floot" is not a word, and I'm reasonably certain you wanted to put "float" there.